# Would it possible to use column header to be row in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have a very simple table `COMPANY` populated with some sample data as shown in the attached screenshot.

```
Create Table COMPANY
(
    ID int, 
    CompanyName varchar(40), 
    CompanyBoss varchar(40), 
    Debt decimal(5,0)
)
```

I would like to select `ID=3` and the result will be

[image]

Would it possible to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Use `UNPIVOT` operator

Comment: What you want is an _unpivot_ which is _possible_ in SQL but is much cleaner to so when you _display_ the data - in a report, web page, form, etc.

Comment: @D Standley, correct me if I am wrong. I mean that this can be done in SQL (`UNPIVOT`) but I should do it in application site (like .NET, etc.) rather than have it done on SQL? Now I think about your comment and it makes a sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still looking for a way to implement in SQL below is one approach -

```
Create Table #COMPANY
(
    ID int, 
    CompanyName varchar(40), 
    CompanyBoss varchar(40), 
    Debt decimal(5,0)
)
Insert into #company
select 1,'company 01','boss 01',10 union all
select 2,'company 02','boss 02',20 union all
select 3,'company 03','boss 03',30 union all
select 4,'company 04','boss 04',40 union all
select 5,'company 05','boss 05',50 union all
select 6,'company 06','boss 06',60
select u.columnname,u.columnvalue from 
(
 select cast(ID as varchar(40)) as ID,CompanyName,CompanyBoss,cast(Debt as varchar(40)) as Debt from #COMPANY where ID = 3
) c
unpivot 
(columnvalue 
    for columnname in (ID,CompanyName,CompanyBoss,Debt)
) u;
```